# How to pass method of String as callable parameter?

Tags: scala

Assume I have a function like:

```
  private def throwUnlessValid[T](func: (String => T)): T = {
    try {
      func()
    } catch {
      case _: Throwable => throw new Error(s"""string: "${s}" is not a numeric""")
    }
  }
```

And I want to call it like:

```
  implicit val intParser: TryParser[Int] = (s: String) => {
    s.trim.isEmpty match {
      case true => 0
      case false => throwUnlessValid[Int](s.toInt)
    }
  }
```

This will fail as the result of `s.toInt`, which is the `Int`. Even though I want to pass in the callable function to be called in the other method.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you need `_.toInt` or `str => str.toInt` (which are equivalent)

Comment: yeah you can do str => s.toInt it will work but this is of no use as i can see you are calling func without the function in like 2 it will give you compilation error.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax is `_.toInt`, which is a shorthand for `s => s.toInt` (or without type inference, `(s: String) => s.toInt`). Generally, search for "scala lambdas" for a lot more information on this.

But the problem is that you call `func()` without passing a string to it. There's also `s` in `throw new Error(s"""string: "${s}" is not a numeric""")`; if `s` is in your scope, you should have `func(s)` instead. Or maybe you want

```
private def throwUnlessValid[T](func: () => T): T = { ... }

throwUnlessValid(() => s.toInt)
```

Using [by-name parameters](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/by-name-parameters.html), you can even write

```
private def throwUnlessValid[T](func: => T): T = { ... }

throwUnlessValid(s.toInt)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a callable function by using `_.toInt`, which is shorthand for the function `x => x.toInt`.

However this isn't going to help because your `throwUnlessValid` function doesn't work, for two reasons:

1. You don't give a `String` argument to `func`
2. You attempt to print `s` which is not a visible to this function

You have two choices:

1. Pass `s` to `throwUnlessValid` and give it to `func`
2. Make `func` into a `=> T` parameter and remove the references to `s` from the `Error` string.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix your throwUnlessValid function.
Currently it accepts as argument a function which takes a string as argument:

```
throwUnlessValid[T](func: (String => T))
```

However then you are trying to call it without any argument: `func()` which obviously won't work. Besides that you also have reference to nonexisting variable s: `${s}` which also should produce error.

In order to fix the throwUnlessValid function you can pass toInt as by-name argument:

```
private def throwUnlessValid[T](code: => T): T = {
    try {
      code
    } catch {
      case ex: Throwable => throw new Error(s"""string: "${ex.getMessage}" is not a numeric""")
    }
  }
```

In other words you don't need to change your existing intParser implementation (including `throwUnlessValid[Int](s.toInt)` call), you only need to change implementation of throwUnlessValid).

Answer (score 0):

If i understant correctly,  you are looking for this.

Actually the problem is that you are not passing string to your function (func) hence it's not working.

```
import scala.util.{Failure, Success, Try}

object Solution1 extends App {
  private def throwUnlessValid[T](func: (String => T)): T = {
    Try {
      func("1")
    } match {
      case Success(_) => //do Something which return T

      case Failure(ex) => throw new Error(s"""string: "${ex}" is not a numeric""")
    }
  }

  implicit val intParser: String => Int = (s: String) => {
    if (s.trim.isEmpty) {
      0
    } else {
      throwUnlessValid[Int](_ => s.toInt)
    }
  }
}
```